# Javascript. All vendor specific CSS inline attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vendor-prefix

I'm currently building an app that creates HTML files. I'm having an issue with Javascript's `.style` for vendor prefixes.

Basically I'm running the following code:

```
function applyTransform(transform) {
    element.style.transform       = transform;
    element.style.WebkitTransform = transform;
    element.style.MozTransform    = transform;
}
```

However, upon inspecting the inline CSS only the styles being applied are those relevant to the current browser.

Am I doing something wrong? or is there a way of forcing vendor prefixed CSS?

Preferably without using `setAttribute('style', '')` as there are other styles being applied.

Comment: Any particular browser is only going to pay attention to its own version; that's the whole point.

Comment: CSS is specifically spec'd to let the user agent ignore stuff it doesn't understand. Maybe you want `data-` attributes instead? What is the goal?

Comment: Pointy makes a good point...

Comment: Absolutely agree. But these templates may be used across other browsers too. Is there any way to set the styles in one browser to enable them across multiple?

Comment: You need to change your whole approach. Dumping a serialised DOM isn't going to give you non-standard stuff that the browser you are using doesn't support.

Comment: So you're hoping to set some styles in the client, and serialize it for reuse elsewhere?

Comment: _"upon inspecting the inline CSS only the styles being applied are those relevant to the current browser"_ This is expected result, yes?

Comment: You can set the style attribute directly though: https://jsfiddle.net/3skkyzeh/1/